# How to add level-by-level game camera following in 2D java game?

Tags: java, 2d, camera

I've been working on my first game recently, and I've built a player tracking camera that works great, but my goal for the game would be to have a camera that is fixed for each area that the player enters, and moves to each new area with the player. Something akin to the game camera from The Legend of Zelda for the NES. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is each room or area of a set size? This will definitely simplify things.

Comment: Yes it would be. My tiles are 16 x 16 pixels and I was aiming for each room to have around 16 x 11 tiles.